# Convert BsonString To BsonArray

Tags: c#, mongodb, casting, bson

I am trying to convert a BsonString to BsonArray as follows:

```
BsonString str = "[{ \"_id\" : \"domain\", \"nm\" : \"Domain\", \"value\" : [\"test.com\"], \"dt\" : ISODate(\"2014-08-04T04:00:00Z\") }]\"";

BsonArray array = str.AsBsonArray;
```

And I get exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray'.

Any ideas on how can I parse a string to a BsonArray object. Without doing it by hand?

Comment: the string define as array already...

Answer (score 4):

Some mucking around, and found the solution

`BsonArray array = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(str);`